# XSLT SUM where ItemCode is like

Tags: xslt

i have the following output and i want to sum every unitPrice where ItemCode = parenID
I do a for-each over every itemCode now i want to sum every unitprice for this item where the parentId is the itemCode. I tried something like that but i think it doesn't work because Unitprice and itemCode are in the same node: `<xsl:variable name="childPrices" select="sum(//row/items/row/unitPrice[./parentId=$itemCode])"></xsl:variable>` Do you have any ideas how to sum these prices? I use xslt 1.0

```
<items>
<row>
<productOption/>
<itemCode> SO(R)-IRDB</itemCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitPrice>2828.0</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<isHauptKomp>ja</isHauptKomp>
<parentID/>
</row>
<row>
<productOption/>
<itemCode>F0007</itemCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitPrice>514.65</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<isHauptKomp>nein</isHauptKomp>
<parentID/>
</row>
<row>
<productOption>true</productOption>
<itemCode>20198</itemCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitPrice>475.0</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<vkPreisHauptkomponente>475.0</vkPreisHauptkomponente>
<isHauptKomp>nein</isHauptKomp>
<parentID> SO(R)-IRDB</parentID>
</row>
<row>
<productOption>true</productOption>
<itemCode>20198</itemCode>
<quantity>2</quantity>
<unitPrice>520.0</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<vkPreisHauptkomponente>520.0</vkPreisHauptkomponente>
<isHauptKomp>nein</isHauptKomp>
<parentID>560-TVC</parentID>
</row>
<row>
<productOption/>
<itemCode> SO-IRDB</itemCode>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<unitPrice>2115.0</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<isHauptKomp>ja</isHauptKomp>
<parentID/>
</row>
<row>
<productOption/>
<itemCode>560-TVC</itemCode>
<quantity>2</quantity>
<unitPrice>2675.0</unitPrice>
<tax/>
<isHauptKomp>ja</isHauptKomp>
<parentID/>
</row>
</items>
```

Comment: In your question you say you want to compare itemCode = parentID, but in your sample input all your parentID elements are empty.

Comment: Please edit your question and add (a) your attempted XSLT and (b) the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to sum every unitprice for this item where the parentId is the itemCode

To do exactly that, it would be best to define a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) that links an item to its parent item. Consider the following minimal example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="row" use="parentID" />

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[not(parentID/text())]">
            <item>
                <xsl:copy-of select="itemCode"/>
                <sum-child-unit-price>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('child', itemCode)/unitPrice)"/>
                </sum-child-unit-price>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input, this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <itemCode> SO(R)-IRDB</itemCode>
    <sum-child-unit-price>475</sum-child-unit-price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <itemCode>F0007</itemCode>
    <sum-child-unit-price>0</sum-child-unit-price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <itemCode> SO-IRDB</itemCode>
    <sum-child-unit-price>0</sum-child-unit-price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <itemCode>560-TVC</itemCode>
    <sum-child-unit-price>520</sum-child-unit-price>
  </item>
</items>
```

Note that this ignores the value of the  `quantity` element in the child items. In XSLT 1.0, it is not possible to sum the results of multiplication directly. If you need this, you will have to do it using either 2 passes or a named recursive template.

---

P.S. To do it the way you have started, you would need to change your expression:

```
sum(//row/items/row/unitPrice[./parentId=$itemCode])
```

to:

```
sum(/items/row[parentID=$itemCode]/unitPrice)
```

But using a *key* is both more convenient and more efficient.